# How to recall calculative field in Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Can you pls help me how to use 'os' in the case statements shown below,thanks in advance

```
select col1,col2, (col3+1) as os,
CASE 
      WHEN CONVERT(date,GETDATE(),103) <=@duedt1  THEN          
        os
      else '0'    
END as 'ot1',
CASE 
      WHEN CONVERT(date,GETDATE(),103) >@duedt1  THEN       
        os
      else '0'    
END as 'ot2'
from t1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1,col2,
CASE 
      WHEN CONVERT(date,GETDATE(),103) <=@duedt1  THEN          
        (col3+1)
      else '0'    
END as 'ot1',
CASE 
      WHEN CONVERT(date,GETDATE(),103) >@duedt1  THEN       
        (col3+1)
      else '0'    
END as 'ot2'
from t1
```

Comment: Thanks mate,but in my case (col3+1) will be a big calculative query...and dont wanna reuse which bloats the query...sorry

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use `CTE` etc or you need to put the expression in here as well. AS you are creating calculated column in this query itself you cannot use it in any other expression in this.

```
;WITH cte_os
AS
(
    SELECT col1, col2, col3+1 [os] FROM t1
)
SELECT col1, col2, os, CASE WHEN `x (lazy)` THEN os ELSE 0 END ot1,.....
FROM cte_os
```

Answer (score 0):

You need subquery

```
SELECT col1,col2,CASE 
                     WHEN CONVERT(date,GETDATE(),103) <=@duedt1 
                     THEN  os
                     ELSE '0'    
                 END as 'ot1',
                 CASE 
                     WHEN CONVERT(date,GETDATE(),103) >@duedt1  
                     THEN os
                     ELSE '0'    
                 END as 'ot2'
FROM (
      select col1,col2, (col3+1) as os
      from t1
     )Z
```

Comment: Thanks hasan,but we already have piece of code lik this on from statement ..confused how to mix it...from tran_post TP 
join POST_SESS PS on TP.SESSION_NO =PS.SESSION_NO 
join ACCOUNT_TRAN AT on TP.SESSION_NO =AT.SESSION_NO
join co on  tp.val_73=co.coid
join ACCOUNT_ZPM az on tp.VAL_13=az.AC_CODE

Comment: what is the problem in what you have ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CROSS APPLY as well.

```
select col1,col2, os,
CASE 
      WHEN CONVERT(date,GETDATE(),103) <=@duedt1  THEN          
        os
      else '0'    
END as 'ot1',
CASE 
      WHEN CONVERT(date,GETDATE(),103) >@duedt1  THEN       
        os
      else '0'    
END as 'ot2'
from t1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT col3 + 1 os) t2
```